# Minify only used functions with gulp

Tags: javascript, import, build, gulp, gulp-uglify

Minify only used functions with gulp ?

/** file.js **/

```
export function oneSample (){
 return 1*1
}

export function twoSample (){
 return 1*1
}
```

/** main.js **/

```
import {oneSample} from './file'
```

/** main.min.js **/

```
export function oneSample (){
 return 1*1
}
```

**My gulp task:**

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src('www/js/main.js')
        .pipe(browserify())
        .pipe(uglifyjs({
                compress: {
                    unused: true
                }
        }))
        .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('platforms/www/js'))
});
```

Gulp function and sample files as above. What I'm trying to do here is to have only the oneSample() function in main.min.js build, but I did not do it.

Only help with a minimized structure is needed by adding imported functions.

Comment: Split the imported functions into two files...?

Comment: Yes it is a solution to this problem. But it would be much better if I could develop something like the example I gave. Thank you